# How to save files loaded on browser

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, networking, browser

I want to save some *PDFs* (Solutions to my workbook so nothing illegal or smth) on a page I can access but there seems to be some kind of authentication in accessing them coz the requests have stuff like signature that change every time
[image: The request]

When I go to that link I get a *403 Error*. As the file gets loaded on my browser I think there must be a way to access it. The page uses Mozilla's *pdf.js* if that helps.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You might be able to do it by putting the headers sent to the request in your code. I can give you a hand if you share the link from where you are trying to get this information.

Comment: @SaC-SeBaS Are you suggesting I scrape the files for the authentication code? I'm sorry I can't share the page coz it's behind authentication and the saved page cannot access the pdf either so I'm guessing the auth code isn't there. I can share the saved page tho if that would help

Comment: @KJ Actually it does load the pdf as you can see in the snippet, and pdf.js just renders the pdf as an iframe (it's html inside). I did try to contact them but they have not responded yet and it's been a while.
<br/>
I mean isn't there a way to like make my browser save the file as it does download the pdf and probably even caches it or smth coz it's 10MBs

Comment: @KJ With the curl address too I get a 403. How do I know if the headers are a one-time-use only or are getting timed out? coz for the latter I think automation could help?